# Year and Month as Primary Key

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a **Payments** table, with **paymentDate** and **licenseId** attributes. I want to make sure that, there is only one payment for a **licenseId** every month. How can I do that? I have seen an answer which says to store incomplete date (day as 00) and make it unique. But, I need exact date too.

I have tried the below things but in vain.

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (`licenseId`, YEAR(`paymentDate`), MONTH(`paymentDate`))
```

```sql
UNIQUE (`licenseId`, YEAR(`paymentDate`), MONTH(`paymentDate`))
```

I am looking for ways, which doesn't include extra year and month attributes in table.

Comment: The primary key is "too important" to use expressions probably, but an UNIQUE key might allow that (can't see it saying otherwise from a quick check of the manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts )

Comment: @jkavalik why is it "too important"? If the data fits, by all means use it as a PK - no surrogate key overhead, natural key - why not?

Comment: @Vérace "too important" in InnoDB structure to be defined on an expression instead of an actual column - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b722c8443726967742f23fa5e0351f2

Comment: @Vérace, PRIMARY KEY's purpose is to make sure that rows are unique. So, It makes sense that functional key is not accepted by it.

Comment: @AppajiChintimi thats not the reason - the unique key in the answer does the same thing and is mostly equivalent to actual PK, the limitation about expressions and PK is technical in nature and afaik specific to mysql-innodb. It could be implemented most probably but they decided not to (currently at least).

Comment: You might want to check out my answer - you **can** have your 3 (1 normal, 2 generated/derived/calculated) fields as the `PRIMARY KEY` - the syntax is a bit fussy, but it works well nonetheless!

Comment: What should happen if a user pays late one month, then it arrives in the next month?  There would be a missing item for the first month (which the PK fixes won't catch) followed by 2 payments in the next month (which is, in a way, "correct").

Comment: @RickJames Now I think about it, I got an idea like this. I'll store `dueDate` attribute along with `paymentDate`. I didn't mention it above because I thought it wouldn't matter. Using that in constraints instead of `paymentDate` fixes late payments. Correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use functions to obtain `PRIMARY KEY`s by using `GENERATED` (or `COMPUTED` or `CALCULATED` and sometimes `VIRTUAL`) fields. However, the virtual keyword also refers to the storage class (`STORED` or `VIRTUAL`) meaning that the generated field is either kept on disk or calculated on-the-fly.

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a61b1ba1fe6db53e8a079d9140894df):

You can have your (`licenceID`, YEAR(`paymentDate`), MONTH(`paymentDate`)) as the `PRIMARY KEY` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
  i INT, 
  a DATE,
  a_y SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (YEAR(a)) STORED,
  a_m SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(a)) STORED,
  
  CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY (i, a_y, a_m)
);
```

and then test:

```
INSERT INTO t (i, a) VALUES (1, NOW());                               ✓
INSERT INTO t (i, a) VALUES (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1 MONTH));  ✓
INSERT INTO t (i, a) VALUES (2, now());                               ✓
```

but:

```
INSERT INTO t (i, a) VALUES (1, '2021-10-30');
```

gives

```
Duplicate entry '1-2021-10' for key 't.PRIMARY'
```

Creating a table with a `PRIMARY KEY` using direct calls to the functions isn't possible:

```
CREATE TABLE s
(
  i INT, 
  a DATE,
  a_y SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(a)) STORED,
  a_m SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(a)) STORED,
  
  CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY (i, (YEAR(a)), (MONTH(a)))
);
```

gives:

```
The primary key cannot be a functional index
```

Doesn't work in [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=712c631f3dcd9709256180e3fa0de517) either. In MySQL, it won't work for the [`VIRTUAL`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=737acec2b1ab1d6c8f4593d3616cfc74) storage class (which PostgreSQL doesn't support anyway).

Comment: Good idea! Still I would consider the generated columns _extra attributes_ :)

Comment: With disk space being so cheap, it's hardly a big deal! :-) I did look at `VIRTUAL` as the storage type, but it [doesn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=737acec2b1ab1d6c8f4593d3616cfc74)!

Comment: Yeah, virtual column are more of a syntactical sugar over expressions.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 8.0.13+ functional key parts should work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `licenseId` int,
  `paymentDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `c` (`licenseId`,(year(`paymentDate`)),(month(`paymentDate`)))
);
```

Can be tested online at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fef176b2ec3a68a1e45acbca122339f7

On the other hand the **Primary key** cannot be defined that way ([tested here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b722c8443726967742f23fa5e0351f2)). So you need to add some other - autoinc or similar, or possibly even `(licenseId, paymentDate)` would be fine as the PK.

Comment: Thank you! Working as expected. Apparently, having parenthesis is different from not having :/

Comment: Check out my answer - you **can** use `generated` fields in `PK`s - MySQL is just a bit fussy how you do this!